# Publish error VS2005 win forms app

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to publish to a FTP site using VS2005.
This worked before and now having come back to it
some months later dos not work.

The error is

Error   3   Could not find required file 'setup.bin' in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bootstrapper\Engine'.

I also get this warning

Warning 2   Item 'Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0' could not be located in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bootstrapper'.

Any ideas??

Malcolm

Answer (score 1):

That error suggests that your Visual Studio install is corrupted.  That particular file is part of the 2.0 redistributable and is included with the default install.  If it's missing that's a pretty bad sign.

Your best bet at this point is repairing your Visual Studio install via Add Remove Programs.

Comment: I reapired VS2005 and then retried to publish. Now I get this, any ideas?
Error 2 SignTool reported an error 'Failed to sign bin\Release\TBRHelp.publish\\setup.exe. SignTool Error: ISignedCode::Sign returned error: 0x80880253

 The signer's certificate is not valid for signing.

SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: bin\Release\TBRHelp.publish\\setup.exe

'. TBRHelp